# AWS: Getting a server to pickup changes to VPC DHCP options

Tags: amazon-web-services, dhcp, amazon-vpc

I have an AWS VPC that by mistake had the default DHCP option set cleared. As a result I have a handful of servers that have the wrong (unresolvable) hostnames and missing settings in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

I have fixed the VPC to use the default DHCP option set. Is there a way to get the servers to pick up these changes?

Answer (score 3):

You can't push the new DHCP settings to the hosts from outside I'm afraid.

You can either:

1. Reboot the instances - probably the best as it ensures that the old settings are not cached in any running programs, or
2. Restart its network stack (e.g. `systemctl restart networking.service` in Ubuntu), or
3. Wait for the DHCP lease to expire, it should then renew with the new settings, or
4. Fix `/etc/resolv.conf` manually if you know what you're doing.
5. If you also need to fix the hostname you can remove `/var/lib/cloud/instance` (it's a symlink) and reboot. That should re-run you (or default) `cloud-init` script that sets the hostname. Test it first on a test instance.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thank you so much for the response. I've tried rebooting but it didn't help. Calling `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname` still returns the wrong hostname (i.e. it's just the ip w/o the domain). I can edit `/etc/resolv.conf`, but those setting are overwritten on reboot. I found that I can stop and restart the instance to resolve the issue. However, the instance in question is an i3 w/ 2 TB of data that will be lost if I stop the instance.

Comment: Just pointing out the obvious @herbrandson that if the data is important you need to have the data on the instance store backed up, in case of hardware failure or operator error (stop / start). Hopefully you can find a way to get your DHCP working without having to stop / start / restore the data.

Comment: Yes, the data is backed up. But, it takes a long time to restore (and I actually need to do this on ~30 nodes). It's not the end of the world if I have to stop and restart... it'll just take forever.

Comment: @herbrandson If reboot doesn't pick up the new settings (which surprises me) it also shouldn't revert your changes if you change `resolv.conf` manually. On the other hand resolv.conf is only used for DNS (nameserver list, search domain) but you also mentioned hostname - that's probably set through `cloud-init`. You can remove `/var/lib/cloud/instance` and reboot - that will re-run your (or default) cloud-init script and reset the hostname. Try it on a test instance first!

Comment: A full stop/start of the instance solved the dhcp issues for me, specifically an incorrect `local-hostname` in ec2metadata.